# Weight Lifting adversely affecting stomach muscles?

Tags: weightlifting, gym, injury-prevention, stomach

I have a friend who used to go to gym for hours everyday and he had a great body.
Then suddenly he started experiencing pain in his stomach area.
So he visited a doctor who told him that there is a 'ball' near our navel region which got 'shifted' a bit due to the weight lifting. Even worse is that it cannot be rectified by surgery.

So he had to spend a month at a specialist camp where they did some massage, therapy after which the problem got solved.
But after a month he had lost all his muscles & was very weak.
Now he does not go to the gym.
I am also scarred a bit by this and I am planning to quit the gym.
Is this a recognised phenomenon internationally?

PS: He used to train under supervision by an expert.

Comment: was he using "suplements"?

Comment: definitely not!

Comment: I've never heard of the phenomenon, but if you have access to the friend's doctor you might want to ask them. It seems like a professional that is familiar with the condition might be of bigger help than the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The most common thing I could find when searching ["ball near navel"](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003277.htm) was a hernia.  A hernia is not normal, but neither is losing all your muscle within a month.  The thing is without an official medical diagnosis it isn't clear exactly what it was--because it could also have been a tumor.  When dealing with a hernia, you really shouldn't do any heavy lifting as it can make things worse.  It usually takes longer than a month to lose significant amounts of muscle.

I will say that there are many people who claim to be an expert who really aren't.  There are also experts who get results in a manner which is not the safest.  I had a personal trainer try to teach me to squat incorrectly.  However, he was not a personal trainer that specialized in weight training, nor was he someone who coached lifters who compete.  At the same time, even though I wouldn't call him an expert, if I told him something was off he would modify his plans to accommodate or if he thought it was something more serious he would have told me to go to the doctor.

There are some risks associated with lifting that you have to consider.  The most common risks are muscle strains and joint pain due to trying to do too much too fast or improper technique.  It does not mean that lifting is bad, or as inherently dangerous as playing tackle football.  Ankle sprains are a common risk in basketball or any other sport where you have to change directions quickly--but that doesn't mean that basketball is to blame for the injury.

Answer (score -2):

The most common problem is shifting of 'navel ball', it can be easily felt by gently pressing thumb on navel (Caution - examine only in the morning with empty stomach to avoid more complexities), This ball is actually a vein, if you're feeling movement of vein in center of navel then everything is alright but in case it is around(up,down,left or right) navel then it may be reason of ur stomachache.
Now..How to fix it?
There r many people claim to fix it by massag and it works but if it is practiced repetitively it becomes a permanent problem so my personal suggestion is don't try this.
Best way to fixing it by exercise which is something like yoga, now let me tell you the procedure-
1. Lay straight on smooth surface (not too soft) & put your hands straight along with your body.
2.Now lift both of ur legs (keep staight) simultaneously and very slowly and make 90° angle.
3.now put your legs down very slowey.
(Do it 2-3 times, in the morning n without drinking water or having breakfast.)
Me & many people in india use this remedy this simple technique will definitely help you.
Best Of Luck.

Comment: As far as I know, "shifting navel ball" is not a condition recognized by science. The "remedy" you suggest might help on some conditions, where strengthening of the lower abdominal wall can help. Or it can make it worse, for other conditions. In any case, such symptoms should always be thoroughly examined by a qualified medical professional.

Comment: I agree with BKE. Until you provide a source (link) that describes the condition and the treatment I remain sceptical. Also your formatting makes it hard to read your answer, consider using paragraphs and/or bullet points to make it more readable.

Comment: If you press into the navel, the "bump" that you feel is what is left of the internal umbilicus, not a vein.